# What is the amortized time for finding the successor element in a binary search tree using inorder algorithm?

Tags: binary-tree, inorder, amortized-analysis

How can I amortized analysis and prove that the successor function (the one the find the next element in the inorder algorithm) is taking at average O(1)? 
Assuming the successor function is operating on the last element found.
Is it even O(1) ? Is it O(log n)?

Comment: Unrelated to [tag:successor-arithmetics].

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about it is that *N* applications of the successor function traverse the entire tree.  What is the complexity of traversing the entire tree?  And what is it when amortised across *N* function calls?